# SailsJS, SocketIO, not getting messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, sails.js

I have a simple login script. I created a method in the **SessionController** called **create** to handle logins. I do all the needed validation and then set the user as active and save them. I also use `User.publishUpdate()` to send the message back to the client.

The problem is that I recieve no messages at all. When the page is loaded I call `User.subscribe(req.socket, users);` for all users so they are all subscribed. Not really sure why the messages aren't sent.

I am using sails 0.10.0.

This is the **subscribe** method which is called on page load:

```
User.find({}).exec(function (error, users) {
    if (error) {
        res.json({
            error: error
        });
    }

    // Subscribe to the model class
    User.subscribe(req.socket);

    // subscribe to the model instance
    User.subscribe(req.socket, users);

    res.send(200);

});
```

And the **create** method for logins (removed code that doesn't pertain to this question):

```
user.active = true;
req.session.authenticated = true;
req.session.User = user;

user.save(function (error, user) {

    if (error) {
        res.send(error, 500);
    }

    User.publishUpdate(user.id, {
        loggedIn: true,
        id: user.id,
        action: ' has logged in'
    });

    res.json(user, 200);
});
```

I am sending the request via sockets to the subscribe and login methods

`socket.get('/user/subscribe');`

`socket.get('/session/create', {//stuff}, callback)`

Comment: Can you post the front-end code you are using to listen for events?

Comment: Just using the `socket.on('message', callback);` event located within the `app.js` file

Answer (score 11, accepted):

PubSub is something that has changed quite a bit with Sails v0.10, and it looks like you're using some v0.9.x semantics.  You can read all about it in the [migration guide](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/reference/Upgrading/Upgrading.md) and the new [Model Methods reference](http://beta.sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/Models/Model-Methods), but as far as what impacts you, the main thing is:

**Messages are no longer published using the "message" event.**  Instead, they are published using the model's identity as the event name.  So, change your listener to:

```
socket.on('user', callback)
```

and you'll start hearing something.

The other thing that pertains to you is that the "Model classrooom" is deprecated, as is using `.subscribe()` with one argument to subscribe to it.  Instead, use `User.watch(req)` to get notifications about newly created Users.

**Update** along with the `.watch()` method, there is also now an `autoWatch` option available in `sails.config.blueprints` (set in your `config/blueprints.js` file) that, if `true`, will revert to v0.9.x behavior: any time a socket is subscribed to a model instance, it will also start "watching" that model class for "create" events.

Comment: I love you man! I had read through the migration docs but couldn't find any mention of the message event changing. Do you have a link to that specific section? There may be more to read up on. Thanks

Comment: I put the link to the v0.10 migration guide in my answer; it's the very first section.  You were probably reading the migration guide on the web site (which is still about migrating to v0.9.x)

Comment: @ScottGress the links are dead.

Comment: 0.10 Migration guide is now here (likely to move again, though): https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/concepts/Upgrading/Upgrading.md

Comment: Actually the docs are all live on http://sailsjs.org now, so they should be there for awhile.  Migration guide is [here](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Upgrading)