# Real time model events in Sails.js 0.10-rc5

Tags: sockets, real-time, deprecated, sails.js, subscribe

I've been playing around with building some realtime functionality using Sails.js version 0.10-rc5 (currently the @beta release).

To accomplish anything, i've been following the sweet SailsCast tutorial on this subject ([sailsCast link](http://irlnathan.github.io/sailscasts/blog/2013/10/10/building-a-sails-application-ep21-integrating-socket-dot-io-and-sails-with-custom-controller-actions-using-real-time-model-events/))
It talks about subscribing to a model via a 'subscribe' action within the model's controller. Then listening to it at the client side, waiting for the server to emit messages. Quite straightforward, although I do not seem to receive any messages.

I'm trying to do this to get real-time updates on anything that changes in my User models, or if new ones get created.. So I can display login status etc. in real time. Pretty much exactly the stuff that's explained in the sailsCast.

In my terminal i'll get two things worth noticing, of which the first is the following:

```
debug: Deprecated:   `Model.subscribe(socket, null, ...)`
debug: See http://links.sailsjs.org/docs/config/pubsub
debug: (⌘ + double-click to open link from terminal)
debug: Please use instance rooms instead (or raw sails.sockets.*() methods.)
```

It seems like the 'subscribe' method has been deprecated. Could anybody tell me if that's correct, and tell me how to fix this? I've been checking out the reference to the documentation in the debug message, although it just points me to the global documentation page. I've been searching for an answer elsewhere, but haven't found anything useful.

The second message I'm getting is:

```
warn: You are trying to render a view (_session/new), but Sails doesn't support rendering views over Socket.io... yet!
You might consider serving your HTML view normally, then fetching data with sockets in your client-side JavaScript.
If you didn't intend to serve a view here, you might look into content-negotiation
to handle AJAX/socket requests explictly, instead of `res.redirect()`/`res.view()`.
```

Now, i'm quite sure this is because I have an 'isAuthenticated' policy added to all of my controllers and actions. When a user is not authenticated, it'll redirect to a session/new page. Somebody must log in to be able to use the application. When I remove the 'isAuthenticated' policy from the 'subscribed' action, the warnings disappear. Although that means anyone will get updates via sockets (when I get it to work), even when they're logged out. - I don't really feel like people just sitting at the login screen, fishing out the real time messages which are intended only for users who are logged in.

Can anyone help me getting the real time updates to work? I'd really appreciate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the socket messages not being received, the issue is that you're following a tutorial for v0.9.x, but you're using a beta version of Sails in which PubSub has gone through some changes.  That's covered in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22544310/sailsjs-socketio-not-getting-messages/22544819#22544819) about the "create" events not being received.

Your second issue isn't about sockets at all; you'll just need to reconsider your architecture a bit.  If you want to to use socket requests to sign users in, then you'll have to be more careful about redirecting them because, as the message states, you can't render a view over a socket.  Technically you could send a bunch of HTML back to the client over a socket, and replace your current page with it, but that's not very good practice.  What you can do instead is, in your `isAuthenticated` policy, check whether the request is happening via sockets (using [req.isSocket](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/08b3b7b0b3b8652d23ee449ac79278d711075365/reference/Request.md#reqissocket)) and if so, send back a message that the front end can interpret to mean, "you should redirect to the login page now".  Something like:

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {

    if ([your auth logic here]) {
        return next();
    }
    else {
        if (req.isSocket) {
            return res.json({status: 403, redirectTo: "/session/new"});
        } else {
            return res.redirect("/session/new");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! - Especially the reference to the migration docs will probably be very helpful in te future. Didn't come across those yet :).